# Function is not executing function inside nested while loop

Tags: python, random

I am new to python and i am trying to run this simple nested while loop program but my code is neither showing any errors nor it is executing the function

```
import random

player_decision = input("Do you want to roll the Dice ? Type y or n:  ").lower()

if player_decision == "y":
    game_on = True

else:

    game_on = False
    print("Thanks for your time!!")

while game_on is True:
    print("Welcome")

    roll_dice = input("Press R to roll the dice or Q to quit the game  ").upper()

    while roll_dice == "R":
        def rolling():
            outcome = random.randint(1,7)
            print(outcome)

    rolling()
```

Comment: Indent `rolling()` to the same level as `def rolling():`, where you have it now it's outside the while loop. Also, you'll loop forever because you never change `roll_dice`, so once you enter the loop you can't escape it.

Comment: Change the `while roll_dice == "R":` to `if roll_dice == "R":`

Comment: Could you describe the intended flow of your game? As it is displayed, I get the strong impression that there are several steps along the way that don't make the program behave the way you expect. 1 quick fix you could add immediately: don't define your function in the while loop. The function gets created again and again this way.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `while roll_dice == "R"` to `if roll_dice == "R"` as stated by [aryerez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11945002/aryerez) in the comments

```py
import random

player_decision = input("Do you want to roll the Dice ? Type y or n:  ").lower()

if player_decision == "y":
    game_on = True

else:

    game_on = False
    print("Thanks for your time!!")

while game_on is True:
    print("Welcome")

    roll_dice = input("Press R to roll the dice or Q to quit the game  ").upper()

    if roll_dice == "R":
        def rolling():
            outcome = random.randint(1,7)
            print(outcome)

    rolling()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 infinite loops here `while game_on is True:` and `if roll_dice == "R":` (once you enter them). You need to change loop entry condition in every iteration to quit the loop.

```
import random

def decision_making():
    player_decision = input("Do you want to roll the Dice ? Type y or n:  ").lower()
    if player_decision == "y":
        game_on = True
    else:
        game_on = False
        print("Thanks for your time!!")
    return game_on
game_on = decision_making()

while game_on is True:
    print("Welcome")
    roll_dice = input("Press R to roll the dice or Q to quit the game  ").upper()
    while roll_dice == "R":
        def rolling():
            outcome = random.randint(1, 7)
            print(outcome)
        rolling()
        roll_dice = input("Press R to roll the dice or Q to quit the game  ").upper()
    game_on = decision_making()
```

Answer (score 0):

you define the `rolling()` in the `if roll_dice == "R":` next level, but you call the `rolling()` in the height level.

Just move the same level.

```
import random

player_decision = input("Do you want to roll the Dice ? Type y or n:  ").lower()

if player_decision == "y":
    game_on = True

else:

    game_on = False
    print("Thanks for your time!!")

while game_on is True:
    print("Welcome")

    roll_dice = input("Press R to roll the dice or Q to quit the game  ").upper()

    if roll_dice == "R":
        def rolling():
            outcome = random.randint(1, 7)
            print(outcome)

        rolling()
```